# Combining two imagepickercontrollers into one function

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to put this in a single function. But I don't know how I'll go about it.

```
@IBAction func selectImages(_ sender: Any) {
    let controller = UIImagePickerController()
    controller.delegate = self
    controller.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    controller.allowsEditing = true
    present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    shareButton.isEnabled = true
}



@IBAction func takingPicture(_ sender: Any) {
    let controller = UIImagePickerController()
    controller.delegate = self
    controller.sourceType = .camera
    present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    shareButton.isEnabled = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign tags (Storyboard as well as code) to button and take decisions inside the function on behalf of tags as :

```
@IBAction func selectImages(_ sender: Any) {
    let controller = UIImagePickerController()
    controller.delegate = self
    if sender.tag == 1 {
      controller.sourceType = .photoLibrary
      controller.allowsEditing = true
    } else {
      controller.sourceType = .camera
    }
    present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    shareButton.isEnabled = true
}
```